# Bootstrap custom break points

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, breakpoints

I am using bootstrap 3.x to build a client site. I have a specific bootstrap break points request from the client:

Small 320px to 768px, 
Medium 769px to 1034px, 
Large 1035px to 1280px, and 
Extra large 1281 plus.

At the same time, I don't want the site to break with future bootstrap version upgrades. The key is that the client will keep using bootstrap classes such as col-md-* col-lg-* etc after I handed on the site and moved on. How can I achieve this? Can somebody share a css or simple scss snippet (new to scss using Scout).

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

**Never ever edit any of the bootstrap core files**, instead overwrite them with custom files -> this way you can update bootstrap.

Lets say you got an folder called bootstrap with all bootstrap core sass files. That create a new folder "custom". In this folder put all files to overwrite the bootstrap core files (like the grid). Than within the sass folder create your style.scss

```
sass
  -bootstrap-sass
    - bootstrap.scss
    - bootstrap
       - alert.scss
       - ...
  -custom
    - custom-grid.scss
  -style.scss
```

Now in you custom-grid.scss put this and replace it with your values:

```
$screen-xs:                  480px !default;
//** Deprecated `$screen-xs-min` as of v3.2.0
$screen-xs-min:              $screen-xs !default;
//** Deprecated `$screen-phone` as of v3.0.1
$screen-phone:               $screen-xs-min !default;

// Small screen / tablet
//** Deprecated `$screen-sm` as of v3.0.1
$screen-sm:                  768px !default;
$screen-sm-min:              $screen-sm !default;
//** Deprecated `$screen-tablet` as of v3.0.1
$screen-tablet:              $screen-sm-min !default;

// Medium screen / desktop
//** Deprecated `$screen-md` as of v3.0.1
$screen-md:                  992px !default;
$screen-md-min:              $screen-md !default;
//** Deprecated `$screen-desktop` as of v3.0.1
$screen-desktop:             $screen-md-min !default;

// Large screen / wide desktop
//** Deprecated `$screen-lg` as of v3.0.1
$screen-lg:                  1200px !default;
$screen-lg-min:              $screen-lg !default;
//** Deprecated `$screen-lg-desktop` as of v3.0.1
$screen-lg-desktop:          $screen-lg-min !default;
```

In your style.scss import all files:

```
// Core Bootstrap
@import "bootstrap-sass/_bootstrap.scss";

// Overwrite bootstrap
@import "custom/custom-grid.scss
...
```

What I am trying to say, this way (if using sass or less) you can overwrite bootstrap core files while keeping the update functionality

Comment: Thank you user2040772. I followed your instruction, however, for some reason it doesn't seem to overwrite the default bootstrap default break points. I am not getting any errors either. Is it possible to overwrite bootstrap defaults with a custom css (not scss) as well. I am using Scout App (not Compass) so I may be limited from using some of the mixins.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SCSS make sure you're using the official [Bootstrap SASS](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) code.

Install it into your project (instructions in readme on GitHub) and then edit the variables defined in lines 271 to 307 `scss/_bootstrap-variables.scss`, compile and that will be all the breakpoints changed throughout.

If there's version upgrade you will however need to recompile the css each time with your customised breakpoints.

Alternatively you can customise all of the settings and download a customised version online on [Bootstrap's Website](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/). You could save the configuration and give that to the client who can reuse it in the future.

Comment: You should never ever make changes to the bootstrap directory. Go for the override option as suggested by user2040772

Comment: If you read my answer correctly it's actually describing exactly @user2040772 said. I'm in no way changing the bootstrap core files, instead merely updating the bootstrap variables partial which does indeed override the core when you recompile.

Comment: You say: "and then **edit** the variables defined in lines 271 to 307 scss/_bootstrap-variables.scss" which I think you never should do. Just copy this to a new file (outside of the bootstrap installation) en paste the same lines in there. This allows you to upgrade anytime the entire bootstrap directory and keep your adjusted variables seperated. The SASS compile is still needed (after every change you make), so it doesn't matter to this at all. If you meant that, I think it is not clear enough in your post.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Are you able to share a code sinppet? I am using Scout App. Any help is much appreciated.