# Modifying Bootstrap breakpoints for iframes

Tags: html, css, reactjs, iframe, bootstrap-4

I am making a wrapper, trying to put my web app into an iframe, but it seems that bootstrap properties inside the app are causing issues. Basically, my app uses a video that is 960x540 and relies on the video being that exact size, not just the aspect ratio. When I put it in a `breakpoint-lg` iframe, ie with a width greater than `992px`, I get unwanted white space on the sides:

[image]

But when I drop the iframe width lower than `992px` (i want it to be exactly `960px`) , then it triggers the `breakpoint-md` and my video maintains its aspect ratio and shrinks, which breaks my app's functionality:

[image]

I have seen other SO threads like this [Bootstrap custom break points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31280384/bootstrap-custom-break-points) which seem similar, but they are either different situations or don't have a confident/accepted answer.

Can anyone guide me on how I can safely modify these breakpoints so that there is no white space, AND the video maintains its native resolution? If there is a method which would allow me to do this within the wrapper html/css, that would be great too. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have control over `<iframe>` contents? If so, change `.container` to `.container-fluid` inside it and you're (most likely) done. If you're not, chances are you won't get much help in here without a [mcve].

Comment: If you think scaling the `<iframe>` down might help you, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500061/transform-scale-dealing-with-remaining-margin-of-initial-size/49500194#49500194).

Comment: I do have control over the app inside the iframe, yes. I'll give that a try and report back thank you!

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Seems like `container-fluid` did the trick! I fixed the size of the iframe to be static so the video ignores all breakpoints now. Thanks so much this is a very elegant fix, I didn't want to mess with custom bootstrap files. If you want me to vote for your answer go ahead and post it again in the answers section.

Comment: Glad I could to help and no, I'm not here for reputation :) Happy coding!